# how can i set a color for my navigation controller buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

How can i add a specific color to my navigation controller background? All i can seem to find is how to set a specific image, but for my need, i only require a background color. Is there a way or is there no SDK-integrated way to change only the color ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you saying the navigationbar color

```
[navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor someColor]];
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. i set it up in my appDelegate and it doesn't seem to change anything :-?

Comment: I don't want color to whole bar instead of i want color to only back button??how it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set background color on UINavigationController. The navigation controller is NOT an UIView!

> The UINavigationController class
>   implements a specialized view
>   controller that manages the navigation
>   of hierarchical content. This class is
>   not intended for subclassing. Instead,
>   you use instances of it as-is in
>   situations where you want your
>   application’s user interface to
>   reflect the hierarchical nature of
>   your content. This navigation
>   interface makes it possible to present
>   your data efficiently and also makes
>   it easier for the user to navigate
>   that content.

[UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: i wasn't clear on the question. I needed to change my navigationBar's color of my navigationController.